# Pandasで文字の列を削除したい

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasで数値の列のみ残し、文字の列を削除したいと考えて以下のコードを実行しましたがエラーでした。

```
df = df.drop(df.select_dtypes(include=str),axis=1)
```

エラーメッセージは

```
TypeError: string dtypes are not allowed, use 'object' instead
```

でした。

どう書き直せばよいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `df.drop()`は使わずに`df.select_dtypes(include='number')`だけにするとか？ [pandas.DataFrameから特定の型dtypeの列を抽出（選択）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-dtype-select/)

Comment: @kunif ご回答ありがとうございます。strを落としたいのですが、floatだけが残ってintも落ちてしまっているようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')
```

でうまくいきました。
ありがとうございました。